# How would you solve this on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a large dataset that contains names and runs scored by batsmen across the domestic seasons of 5 cricket playing countries. You need to find the number of batsmen in each country who have scored within 500 runs of the leader in that particular country. For example, if the leader in India has 1500 runs, the number of Indian batsmen with more than 1000 runs. The dataset contains 3 columns, name, runs and country.

Comment: Homework, nice! If you run into problems, you can ask a specific question here. Don't forget to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward case for the max window function:

```
select country, count(*)
from (
    select country, runs, max(runs) over (partition by country) max_runs
    from batsmen
) batsmen_with_max_runs
where runs > max_runs - 500
group by country
```